# Does MongoDB takes the DBRefs inside a document as a full size document for the 16MB threshold?

Tags: mongodb

For example, I have a document called Country that contains multiple DBRefs to another document called Cities. If each City document has the size of 8MB for example, I only can store two DBRefs in the Country document, or the DBRef is just a reference and is not taking the full size of the document referenced?

Comment: DBRefs are like foreign keys.  Provide the ID of the other collection in the first collection.  This contrasts to embedded documents where the 'city' sub documents are contained inside the 'country' document.  See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/ for details about DBRef implementation.  If using a DBREf it is small - only the key of the referenced document is embedded in the parent document.  This piece of information is part of the 16MB limit, not the whole document in another collection.

Comment: @barrypicker So for example, if Country can only store 2 Cities of 8MB each one, it also can store a lot more of DBRef referencing to Cities?

Comment: Yes.  That is correct.  The reference itself is only a matter of a few bytes.  For arguments sake, let's say each DBRef is 16 bytes (16 bytes is arbitrary and fictional - there is no reason to believe they are 16 bytes - could be more, but could be less - I selected this value to make the math easy).  Since there is a 16MB limit on a document you could have almost a million city references in a single country document.  I say "almost" because the country document itself has bytes also that must be accounted for and part of the 16MB limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare the two different ways to store relational data:

1. Embedded data
2. Referenced data

### **Embedded Data:**

**Countries collection**
(city information is embedded as an array of sub documents in country document)

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e336c2bc0a47e0a958a2b9c"),
    "name" : "France",
    "cities" : [
        {
            "name" : "Paris",
            "population" : 2190327
        },
        {
            "name" : "Marseille",
            "population" : 862211
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e336c85c0a47e0a958a2b9d"),
    "name" : "Germany",
    "cities" : [
        {
            "name" : "Berlin",
            "population" : 3520031
        },
        {
            "name" : "Hamburg",
            "population" : 1787408
        },
        {
            "name" : "Munich",
            "population" : 1450381
        }
    ]
}
```

### **Referenced Data**

(Cities are in separate collection)

**Cities collection**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e336cfdc0a47e0a958a2b9e"),
    "name" : "Paris",
    "population" : 2190327
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e336cfdc0a47e0a958a2b9f"),
    "name" : "Marseille",
    "population" : 862211
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e336d11c0a47e0a958a2ba0"),
    "name" : "Berlin",
    "population" : 3520031
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e336d11c0a47e0a958a2ba1"),
    "name" : "Hamburg",
    "population" : 1787408
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e336d11c0a47e0a958a2ba2"),
    "name" : "Munich",
    "population" : 1450381
}
```

**Countries collection**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e336c2bc0a47e0a958a2b9c"),
    "name" : "France",
    "cities" : [
        DBRef("cities", ObjectId("5e336cfdc0a47e0a958a2b9e"), "mydatabase"),
        DBRef("cities", ObjectId("5e336cfdc0a47e0a958a2b9f"), "mydatabase")
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e336c85c0a47e0a958a2b9d"),
    "name" : "Germany",
    "cities" : [
        DBRef("cities", ObjectId("5e336d11c0a47e0a958a2ba0"), "mydatabase"),
        DBRef("cities", ObjectId("5e336d11c0a47e0a958a2ba1"), "mydatabase"),
        DBRef("cities", ObjectId("5e336d11c0a47e0a958a2ba2"), "mydatabase")
    ]
}
```

### **Evaluation**

When comparing these two we can see the size of the documents differ.  When using references the size of the country document is smaller.  This example is academic at best, but consider if the sub documents are large...

**Size of documents** (in bytes)

*Embedded documents:*

```
Object.bsonsize(db.countries.findOne({name: "France"}))
144

Object.bsonsize(db.countries.findOne({name: "Germany"}))
189
```

*Referenced versions*

```
Object.bsonsize(db.countries.findOne({name: "France"}))
166


Object.bsonsize(db.countries.findOne({name: "Germany"}))
224
```

### **Conclusions**

Well, the whole point of this exercise was to show the embedded documents are heavier than referenced documents, but the sub documents are so small (in this example) it caused this experiment to show the opposite!  The embedded documents are smaller than the references because ObjectIds are heavy (relatively).  Consider if the embedded sub documents are large.  This will sway the experiment the other way.  You can experiment with different data sets to see the differences in sizes to help determine the best schema approach.  Size limits are only one aspect of schema design.  DBRef lookups are far slower than embedded documents because each sub document is essentially a query itself.  Also, consider the idea of embedding an ObjectID as a raw data point instead of an actual DBRef - this could yield a smaller and faster approach.  Some articles have described using this approach as a poor-mans DBRef and advise against DBRef.

Please add comments or questions and I will be happy to discuss!